# scala play 2.5 and dependency injection into actor

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, akka

I am a little confused with the play documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka

Looking at the examples, one can start an actor from a controller:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import akka.actor._ 
import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val actor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[AnActor], "anActor")

  //...
}
```

Or one can rely on Guice to instantiate that actor

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import actors.ConfiguredActor

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
    def configure = {
        bindActor[AnActor]("anActor")
    }
}
```

When the actor is instantiated by Guice, it is possible to inject a dependency into it

```
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._
import play.api.Configuration

class AnActor @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends Actor {
    //...
}
```

However, starting that actor from a controller raises an

```
[IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class AnActor for arguments []]
```

Is there a way to inject a service into a non-Guice-instantiated actor?

Comment: Can you inject `Configuration` into `Application`, then provide it as a parameter? The actor creation would then become something like `val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new AnActor(configuration)), "anActor")`

Comment: Yes, this is what I do at the moment.  However, this does not seem very elegant. Moreover, my final goal is to have services injected into child actors and I would like to avoid having to pass them as argument from constructor to constructor.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bindActorFactory](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0/api/java/play/libs/akka/AkkaGuiceSupport.html#bindActorFactory-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) and then use a factory for creating actors in controllers.

> Bind an actor factory. This is useful for when you want to have child actors injected, and want to pass parameters into them, as well as have Guice provide some of the parameters.

You nead a Factory in your Actor's companion object.

```
import akka.actor._

object AnActor {

  trait Factory {
    def apply(): Actor
  }
}

class AnActor @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) extends Actor {

  def receive = ???

}
```

You use bindActorFactory in your Module

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

import actors._

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActorFactory[AnActor, AnActor.Factory]
  }
}
```

Then, you could instantiate your actors from your controller using the actor system (so they will be childs of /user actor) and guice will do its magic.

```
class LocationsController @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem){

  def injectedChild2(create: => Actor, name: String, props: Props => Props = identity)(implicit system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = {
    system.actorOf(props(Props(create)), name)
  }

  val actor1: ActorRef = injectedChild2(childFactory(),"anActor1")(actorSystem)
  val actor2: ActorRef = injectedChild2(childFactory(),"anActor2")(actorSystem)

}
```

You could add parameters to the Factory.apply if you like to pass parameters that aren't injected by guice, in this case you need to annotate this parameters with `@Assisted`

```
object AnActor {

  trait Factory {
    def apply(someValue: String): Actor
  }
}

class AnActor @Inject() (configuration: Configuration,@Assisted someValue: String) extends Actor {

  def receive = ???

}

class LocationsController @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem){

  def injectedChild2(create: => Actor, name: String, props: Props => Props = identity)(implicit system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = {
    system.actorOf(props(Props(create)), name)
  }

  val actor1: ActorRef = injectedChild2(childFactory("value fom actor 1"),"anActor1")(actorSystem)
  val actor2: ActorRef = injectedChild2(childFactory("value from actor 2"),"anActor2")(actorSystem)

}
```

The example and the method `injectedChild2` are taken from the [original Play example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-child-actors) but modified to create actors from controllers.

**UPDATE:**

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140582/3517383) to know why you should avoid create actors from a controller, in the words of James Roper.