# Play Framework, Akka, Guice : How to create multiple instances of an actor (which has dependencies) with Guice inside controller?

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, akka, guice

There is an example in play framework doc (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAkka) that explains how to inject actor (which has dependencies to be injected) into controller:

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() 
(@Named("configured-actor") configuredActor: ActorRef)
(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds

      def getConfig = Action.async {
        (configuredActor ? GetConfig).mapTo[String].map { message =>
          Ok(message)
        }
      }
    }
```

But as I understand, it creates a single instance of the actor (e.g., singleton).

I need to create multiple instances of `configuredActor` inside the controller.

There is also an example which demonstrates how to create child actors (which has dependencies to be injected) instances from parent actor

```
object ParentActor {
  case class GetChild(key: String)
}

class ParentActor @Inject() (
    childFactory: ConfiguredChildActor.Factory
) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {
  import ParentActor._

  def receive = {
    case GetChild(key: String) =>
      val child: ActorRef = injectedChild(childFactory(key), key)
      sender() ! child
  }
}
```

I've tried to apply this technique inside controller, but `injectedChild(childFactory(key), key)` requires (implicitly) actor context

```
def injectedChild(create: => Actor, name: String, props: Props => Props = identity)(implicit context: ActorContext): ActorRef = ...
```

But I need to create this actor from ActorSysem (e.g. /user).

(I thought to get the context of `/user` actor, but how? is that correct?)

What is a proper way to create multiple instances of an actor with Guice outside parent actor (for example, inside controller)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way of obtaining the ActorContext from outside of an actor, but if you like to create child actors from the /user actor you could do directly `system.actorOf`.

The problem is like you said, that `InjectedActorSupport` needs an ActorContext.
But if you look the trait, it doesn't do anything fancy, just

```
  def injectedChild(create: => Actor, name: String, props: Props => Props = identity)(implicit context: ActorContext): ActorRef = {
    context.actorOf(props(Props(create)), name)
  }
```

So, the solution is to extend the trait and add a method that receives the ActorSystem instead of the ActorContext.

```
  def injectedChild2(create: => Actor, name: String, props: Props => Props = identity)(implicit system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = {
    system.actorOf(props(Props(create)), name)
  }
```

In fact, you could even add the method to the controller directly but it is not convenient if you want to do this in multiples controllers.

**UPDATE:**

although this is technically correct I assumed (correctly) that the lack of a method that receives an ActorSystem was intended.

So, I've [asked to the play dev team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/5vKCVhHbBKc) and James Roper has answered:

> The reason for this is that it's generally not good practice to create many actors directly from outside the actor system, because **you can't supervise them** - that is, you can't say what should happen when they crash (should they be stopped, restarted, escalated etc?). In all the scenarios where I've wanted to create an actor from a controller, it's always ended up being a better design for me to not do that, rather, to send a message to another manager actor to create the child actor. When you do this, it **gives you a lot more flexibility in future**, for example, lets say in future you have a requirement that when a user resubmits the same operation, it shouldn't start a new actor but should connect to the existing actor. If you have a manager actor, that's very easy to do, you can atomically check if the manager actor has a child for that operation already, and create a new child if necessary. If not, it's not possible. And then in future you move to a multi node setup, and you might decide to shard your actors across a cluster - again, very easy **if you were using a manager actor because all you need to do is replace the manager actor with cluster sharding, or put a clustered consistent hashing router in front of your manager, but if creating actors directly from the controller, not possible**.